# Install chrome browser headless Selenium Python in EC2

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run a Python Selenium session in headless mode on my EC2 instance.
I have a hard time trying to use Chrome in headless mode.

```
import os
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1366,768")

if options.headless:
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/71 Safari/537.36')

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/ec2-user/certs/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```

I receive the below error but I do not understand it:

> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have
>   wrong permissions. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Could you guide me on the steps to work around this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this issue? Can you use your EC2 interface to change the permissions for `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: `Amazon EC2` instance uses `Linux` so you need a linux version of chromedriver not `chromedriver.exe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer guided me to this link: https://www.tomordonez.com/install-chromedriver-linux.html  Which helped me to solve my issue. Thx!